# Built in webcam not working on ubuntu 12.04 Lenovo X230 (PART 2)

Tags: webcam

The cam seems to work on kamerka software but only when firefox is closed. I am trying to cam on www.swingingheaven.co.za, but its not working (I am using firefox).

the output of `lsmod | grep uvc` is:

```
uvcvideo 72627 1 videodev 98259 2 uvcvideo
```

the output of lsusb is:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bdb:1926 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 147e:2020 Upek 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 5986:02d2 Acer, Inc
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Firefox camera settings, and set it to the right camera? This could also clarify why the camera only works in another application when Firefox isn't open.

I don't have any experience with Firefox, but it was set to the wrong one in Chrome for me, I had to manually set it to the right built-in webcam.

Comment: Dont know what settings to change in firefox

Comment: I don't know either as I don't use Firefox, but Chrome displays a little camera icon in the URL bar when trying to video chat, and if you click on that you can choose a camera.